# Upload advanced custom field text link array with csv

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic, advanced-custom-fields, import, csv

On my webshop I have to see a button with a link to ad pdf file.
For every product that button need to have a different link and a different button title name.

I built the webshop with woocommerce where I used Advanced Custom fields to show the buttons with a pdf link.
In ACF I used a link array.
On the product page I can change the title text of the link manually.

But.
There are more than 1000 products. So it's not possible to do this manually.
I imported a csv with the right header names. And importing the columns with links to the buttons works properly.

In the php code I used this standard acf code:

```
<?php 
$link = get_field('link');
if( $link ): 
    $link_url = $link['url'];
    $link_title = $link['title'];
    $link_target = $link['target'] ? $link['target'] : '_self';
    ?>
    <a class="button" href="<?php echo esc_url( $link_url ); ?>" target="<?php echo esc_attr( $link_target ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $link_title ); ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So, what meta data I have to give in my csv file to fill in the link title?
--> The title on the button.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a var_dump() on $link:

```
var_dump('<pre>', $link);
```

then you will see all array keys and you can choose the one you need.